# AngularJS Link function: difference between element.attr and link's attrs?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS's link function we have `link: function(scope, element, attrs)`. What is the difference between `element.attr()` and the link's `attrs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6WzwHjbNhasreMKpnrB8?p=preview):

```
app.directive("test",function($compile){
  return {
      restrict:"A",
      link:function(scope,element,attrs){
          console.log("attrs:" + attrs.name);
          console.log("element.attr:" + element.attr("name"));
      }
   };
});
```

- `attrs.name`: display the `resolved value`.
- `element.attr("name")`: display the `original expression`

Basically, `attrs` displays the value **resolved based on current scope**, `element.attr()` displays the **original string assigned to the HTML**

Answer (score 1):

The element is a jqlite or jquery object which has [a method](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) `attr`

Whereas attrs defined by Angular documentation is

> iAttrs - instance attributes - Normalized list of attributes declared
>   on this element shared between all directive linking functions.

See compile documentation for `Attributes` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile